# Googlesheet with scripts

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfnxY.jpg)

Hi all, 
I want to create script to full in L column: "Defaul" when C:C is not blank and one cell in column L is empty. Please help!

Comment: Could you clarify whether you mean "I want to create script" or "I want others to create script for me"

Comment: Why are you trying to do that with Javascript? Google Spreadsheets has similiar functionality..

Comment: i can't find function's google Spreadsheet to do it, please help me!